# Procedure variables acting different depending on @ or DECLARE

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In a procedure, I'm trying to record the name and category from two different tables and put them into two separate variables. For some reason, the **first variable gets the same value as the second variable**.

So **TitleName** will have the same value as **CategoryName**, but they're completely unrelated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `TestProc` () BEGIN

DECLARE TitleName TINYTEXT;
DECLARE CategoryName TINYTEXT;

SELECT name FROM titles_table WHERE titles_table.id = 20 INTO TitleName;
SELECT category FROM categories_table WHERE categories_table.id = 3 INTO CategoryName;

SELECT TitleName, CategoryName;

END
```

**Outputs: "My Category", "My Category"
..... Should be: "My Title", "My Category"**

**BUT**: if I add an @ symbol in front of the variable names, it works as expected, and both variables get unique values.

**OR** if I remove the second SELECT line (SELECT category), then TitleName keeps the correct value.

**The following procedure edit works, but why?:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `TestProc` () BEGIN

DECLARE TitleName TINYTEXT;
DECLARE CategoryName TINYTEXT;

SELECT name FROM titles_table WHERE titles_table.id = 20 INTO @TitleName;
SELECT category FROM categories_table WHERE categories_table.id = 3 INTO @CategoryName;

SELECT @TitleName, @CategoryName;

END
```

**Correctly Outputs: "My Title", "My Category"**

My question is: why does it work when I use @ symbols?

I've already declared the variables using DECLARE, so in this case, what difference would @ and DECLARE make? I want the variable scope to finish when it reaches END, which is why I went with DECLARE. Any ideas why this is giving me different results? I'm using MySQL WorkBench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to have been with my version of MySQL (perhaps a bug).
I upgraded to the newest version as of this date, and now it's working correctly.

The version I had with the issues was: 5.7.10
I upgraded to: 5.7.17

Answer (score 0):

The difference between DECLARE variables and @-variables is that DECLARE variables are local variables (visible inside the block) whereas the @-variables are session variables (they maintain the state throughout the connection).

If use session variables and you call another procedure which uses the same variable, the change is effective also in the calling procedure). Another difference is that with DECLARE you define a specific datatype.

When you use variables inside a procedure, you should use local variables (declare) in order to avoid conflicts. Use a prefix/suffix in the variable name to make sure the variable names do not conflict with the column names. Instead of:

```
DECLARE TitleName TINYTEXT;
...
```

You should use:

```
DECLARE v_TitleName TINYTEXT;

SELECT name INTO v_TitleName
FROM titles_table 
WHERE titles_table.id = 20;
```

Comment: The problem in my first procedure example is that the variables both get the same value, even though they're both getting info from two different tables with different values. But when I add @, it works as expected. Not sure why. The DECLARE variables should maintain their value within BEGIN and END, so I don't want to use @, as I want the variable to finish once it reaches END.